# Drawing graph from Hashmap using Prefuse in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, prefuse

I have a **hashmap** and I want to draw a **graph** with it. All the values of the hashmap will be node and they will all be connected with a single common node given by user. Also, the keys of the hash map will be used to label the directed edge between the root and the nodes.

I'm new to **prefuse**. Is it possible to do this ? Some related examples will help me greatly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did http://prefuse.org/doc/manual/introduction/example/ not help?

Comment: More examples are in the [`demos`](https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse/tree/master/demos/prefuse/demos) directory of the distribution. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your chosen approach.